# What impact of java app holding the same log file twice?

Tags: java, performance, log4j, quartz-scheduler

on dev machine when inspecting open files of a running java app (which uses log4j 1.4) I see:

```
$ lsof -a -p 26676 | grep -v "jar" | grep -v ".so"
COMMAND   PID         USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
java    26676 bartyushenko    1w   REG                8,7      102 3407873 /home/.../logs/server/server.cron.log
java    26676 bartyushenko    1w   REG                8,7      102 3407873 /home/.../logs/server/server.cron.log
```

Cron.log is used for logging cron-relative logs (sorry for bad style). In general there are nearly nothing logged.

What I am wondering is: what impact it could have in worst case and how to check that?